# What is the default web server on which Django site runs and how can I make my django site https enabled?

Tags: django, ssl, https, webserver

I have my django site www.medicaremantra.com up and running, but right now it is http only, I need to make it https enabled, On which default server does a django site runs and where I can deploy the ssl certificates configuration to make it https enabled or is there any other way to achieve https configuration in django?

Comment: There is no "default server". It runs on the server you set it up on when you deployed it.

Answer (score 0):

First you should figure out whether you're using nginx or Apache (you'll most likely be using one of these two).

Then, follow the instructions in [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-commercial-certificate-authority) to configure the appropriate webserver.